# pandas converting floats to strings without decimals

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['2', '3', 'nan'],
        ['0', '1', '4'],
        ['5', 'nan', '7']
    ])

print df

   0    1    2
0  2    3  nan
1  0    1    4
2  5  nan    7
```

I want to convert these strings to numbers and sum the columns and convert back to strings.

Using `astype(float)` seems to get me to the number part.  Then summing is easy with `sum()`.  Then back to strings should be easy too with `astype(str)`

```
df.astype(float).sum().astype(str)

0     7.0
1     4.0
2    11.0
dtype: object
```

That's almost what I wanted.  I wanted the string version of integers.  But floats have decimals.  How do I get rid of them?

I want this

```
0     7
1     4
2    11
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add a `astype(int)` in the mix:

```
df.astype(float).sum().astype(int).astype(str)

0     7
1     4
2    11
dtype: object
```

---

Demonstration of example with empty cells.  This was not a requirement from the OP but to satisfy the detractors

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['2', '3', 'nan', None],
        [None, None, None, None],
        ['0', '1', '4', None],
        ['5', 'nan', '7', None]
    ])

df

      0     1     2     3
0     2     3   nan  None
1  None  None  None  None
2     0     1     4  None
3     5   nan     7  None
```

Then

```
df.astype(float).sum().astype(int).astype(str)

0     7
1     4
2    11
3     0
dtype: object
```

Because the OP didn't specify what they'd like to happen when a column was all missing, presenting zero is a reasonable option.

However, we could also drop those columns

```
df.dropna(1, 'all').astype(float).sum().astype(int).astype(str)

0     7
1     4
2    11
dtype: object
```

Comment: I believe you were just now the victim of some strategic downvoting. +1 to counter that and because your answer came way before the other.

Comment: This won't handle a row with all missing values.

Comment: @dlm sure it does.. I just ran example.  If you have a specific case, why don't you ask a question to clear it up.  This answer satisfied the requirements of the OP.  If you didn't find it useful, you don't have to up-vote.  But a down-vote is a declaration that the answer is not useful when it clearly was, as it solved the problem presented.

Comment: Wrong solution, using `sum` changes the final result

Answer (score 39):

## For pandas >= 1.0:

[`<NA>` type was introduced for 'Int64'](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html). You can now do this:

```
df['your_column'].astype('Int64').astype('str')
```

And it will properly convert `1.0` to `1`.

---

## Alternative:

If you **do not want to change the display** options of all pandas, @maxymoo solution does, you can use `apply`:

```
df['your_column'].apply(lambda x: f'{x:.0f}')
```

Comment: Great! `astype('Int64').astype('str')` worked for converting individual columns. Since it's true reformatting of data type, I'd prefer this over changing display option.

Answer (score 32):

Converting to `int` (i.e. with `.astype(int).astype(str)`) won't work if your column contains nulls; it's often a better idea to use string formatting to explicitly specify the format of your string column; (you can set this in `pd.options`):

```
>>> pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.0f}'.format
>>> df.astype(float).sum()
0     7
1     4
2    11
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer I was looking for!

Comment: I believe the correct method for a dataframe is `applymap`, not `map`.

Comment: @IanS yes you're right, I used map because because I summed the columns before doing the formatting

Comment: why does .format() convert to object here? It is implicitly converting from float to string?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ I guess the format is used in the conversion. Maybe in the series formatter as mentioned in [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/options.html#available-options).

Answer (score 3):

Add `astype(int)` right before conversion to a string:

```
print (df.astype(float).sum().astype(int).astype(str))
```

Generates the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

The above didnt work for me so im going to add my solution

Convert to a string and strip away the .0:

```
db['a] = db['a'].astype(str).str.rstrip('.0')
```

Comment: if it ends with 0, the 0 is also removed.
Example:
input: 1230.0

expected output: 1230

real output: 123

Answer (score 1):

based on [toto_tico's solution - alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62018600/17134750) , minor changes to avoid null case become `nan`

```
df['your_column'].apply(lambda x: f'{x:.0f}' if not pd.isnull(x) else '')
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions, when converting to string, will turn `NaN` into a string as well. To get around that and retain `NaN`, use:

```
c = ...  # your column
np.where(
    df[c].isnull(), np.nan,
    df[c].apply('{:.0f}'.format)
)
```

Retaining NaN allows you to do stuff like convert a nullable column of integers like `19991231, 20000101, np.nan, 20000102` into date time without triggering date parsing errors.